# Ошибка при создании файла в любой папке

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, uwp

Пытаюсь создать файл на диске D:\NewFolder\image.jpg, система доходит до создания

```
var destinationFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(localSettings.Values["folderPath"].ToString() + @"\image.jpg");
```

и выдаёт ошибку.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Отказано в доступе. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
```

В чём может быть проблема, как мне дать доступ программы до любой выбранной папки, и создания/редактирования там файлов, других папок?

Comment: Запускать с правами администратора?

Comment: @Ivan программа написана на UWP, она по дефолту не запускается от администратора. Ей надо дать какой то доступ до определенных данных